# Safely Sending Credentials to Users

Tags: security

I need to safely send credentials created by the admin to users in a secure fashion. Currently, creds have been sent to users via plain text email (which is a huge security concern).

How can I securely send a user their username and password without needing to use an email encryption plugin or other software?

I'm struggling to find a solution in literature. Everyone seems to seek secure access to user-defined credentials through a website.

I appreciate any responses I receive which lead me closer to finding and implementing a secure credential transfer.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer**:

See this post on the Information Security StackExchange.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/58509/sending-passwords-to-someone-remotely

Answer (score 3):

You may get better answers on the [Information Security stackexchange site](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

But it's typically best to avoid having to send users their password. Let them create a password when they register with your application.

If you do need to create their user account for them, you could send them the password in an encrypted email or over secure IM. But even then, force them to change the password on first log on. You don't want anyone to know the user's password beside the user themselves.

Comment: I will post on Information Security, thanks. But your suggestion still does not apply to situation (of which I did not specify in my post). These are Database user credentials. I, dba, create and provide them with creds. The end goal is to setup user groups, corresponding to individual department access requirements and create individual users who are members of one or more groups.